# Group by, having using in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have problem with mysql query.
I need get full rows with max value rating.
 For example I have table **recipes**

**rating     |    id      |   class**

```
4.1  | 1 | soup
4.2 | 3 | soup
4.9 | 4 | soup
4.8 | 5 | salads
4.3 | 6 | dishes9

SELECT MAX(rating) rat, id, class FROM recipes GROUP BY class
```

And I get result:

**rat     |    id      |   class**

```
4.9 | 1 | soup
4.8 | 5 | salads
4.3 | 6 | dishes
```

So in first row(where class='soup') I get  trully max rating - 4.9, but in this row id has value 1, not 4.

When I use **having**

```
SELECT MAX(rating) rat, id, class FROM recipes GROUP BY class HAVING rating=rat
```

result become

**rat     |    id      |   class**

```
4.8 | 5 | salads
4.3 | 6 | dishes
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What would you like to get if you have two id's of the same class with the same maximum rating. Eg in your fisrt list, if you add the line 4.9|7|soup, do you want rows for both 4 and 7 returned? or just one picked at random?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use an `IN()` subquery to find the corresponding `id`s of the rows with `MAX(rat)`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipes
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM recipes GROUP BY class HAVING rat = MAX(rat)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT r1.*  FROM recipes r1
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(rating) rat, class FROM recipes GROUP BY class) r2
    ON r1.class = r2.class AND r1.rating = r2.rat;
```